# What is the meaning for the convention "runSomething" in the Haskell community?

Tags: haskell, newtype

I've seen in some docs and tutorials:

- [runReader](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Reader.html)
- [runState](https://wiki.haskell.org/State_Monad#Primitives)
- [runState](http://www.learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more)

What is the abstract concept that this pattern covers? What does running something mean in Haskell?

Side question, is there a tag for things you always wanted to know but were too afraid to ask?

Comment: Functions such as `run*`, `eval*`, and `exec*` have to do with particular monads (Reader, and State in this case).  How deep an answer regarding Monads would you like?

Comment: As general as possible. I would like to understand the tutorials that seem to asume that I understand this convention.

Comment: Perhaps you should read the wikibook [chapter on the State monad](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_monads/State).

Comment: These often just remove a `newtype` wrapper, exposing the underlying type. Sometimes we also find `unSomething, getSomething, appSomething` for a similar unwrapping. E.g. `appEndo, getDual`. I wish the convention were more uniform.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Haskell, the convention `runSomething` means 'execute the effects described inside the given argument, and return the resulting value'.

I purposely said 'effects' because I was being fuzzy; in Haskell you use the type system to describe different effects that might happen, like doing I/O, or modifying state, etc. So depending on the exact type, different effects might be run before the final value is returned.

Comment: And for completeness: `evalSomething` is for when you don't care about the effects and want the lightest-weight possible way to get the value it computes, while `execSomething` is for when you only care about the effects and the value it computes at the end is irrelevant.